# VBA replace second occurence of string

Tags: excel, vba

I need to replace the second occurence of this word on highlighted cells. So far, I have this code which replaces all occurences.

```
Selection.Replace What:="NORTH", Replacement:="N", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Find` and `FindNext` to locate the second occurrence, and then replace it.

```
Dim fr As Range
    'sample data
Cells.Clear
s1 = "North"
s2 = "South"
arr = Array(s1, s2)
For i = 1 To 10
    Cells(i, 1) = arr(Int(Rnd * 2))
Next i
    'code
With [a1:a10]
    .FindNext(.Find(What:="North", After:=[a10])).Value = "N"
End With
```

This finds the first occurrence of 'North' **after** cell `a10` (the `Find` method wraps round the range), and then finds the next occurrence after the first, and changes it's value to 'N'.

Ref.:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext

Comment: *This works except for when 'North' is in the first cell* That's because your omitted `after` argument defaults to `after:=a1`.  Always a good idea in VBA to define all your arguments -- at least on the first call to a routine with `optional` and/or `default_to_the_ last_run` arguments

Answer (score 0):

For versatility and reusability, here is a function you can use. You can pass in the specific instance you want to find as well as other options. The function returns a boolean representing if the specified instance was found and replaced (if you want to make use of that return value).

```
Sub Example()
     ReplaceInstance Selection, "NORTH", "N", 2, MatchWhole:=True, MatchCase:=True
End Sub

Public Function ReplaceInstance(Rng As Range, FindText As String, Replacement As String, Optional Instance As Long = 1, _
Optional MatchWhole As Boolean, Optional MatchCase As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Start As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For Each Cell In Rng
        If TypeName(Cell.Value) <> "Error" Then
            ' Match whole cell
            If MatchWhole Then
                If StrComp(Cell, FindText, IIf(MatchCase, 0, 1)) = 0 Then
                    i = i + 1
                    If i = Instance Then
                        Cell = Replacement
                        ReplaceInstance = True
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                End If
            ' Match any part of cell
            Else
                Start = InStr(1, Cell, FindText, IIf(MatchCase, 0, 1))
                Do While Start <> 0
                    i = i + 1
                    If i = Instance Then
                        Cell = Left(Cell, Start - 1) & Replace(Cell, FindText, Replacement, Start, 1, IIf(MatchCase, 0, 1))
                        ReplaceInstance = True
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                    Start = InStr(Start + 1, Cell, FindText, IIf(MatchCase, 0, 1))
                Loop
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```